# JOOQ: How to serialize POJO column to JSON

Tags: mysql, json, jooq

I'm trying to write a JSON column to MySQL using JOOQ and Jackson but I'm not sure why it isn't serialized as JSON but as a toString representation.

Here is a table for which I generate JOOQ definitions:

```sql
create table JsonPayload
(
    name              varchar(127) primary key,
    rules             JSON                 not null,
    defaultValue      tinyint(1) default 0 not null
);
```

This are the classes I'd like to bind my model.

```kotlin
    data class RuleTest(val name: String, val test: Boolean)

    data class Rule(val name: String, val test: Boolean, val rule: RuleTest)

    data class JsonPayload(val name: String, val rules: List<Rule>, val defaultValue: Boolean)
```

Insertion code:

```kotlin
    dsl.insertInto(JSONPAYLOAD)
        .set(dsl.newRecord(
            JSONPAYLOAD,
            JsonPayload(
                "Test",
                listOf(Rule("rule1", false, RuleTest("rule1", false)),
                    Rule("rule2", true, RuleTest("rule1", false))),
                true
            )
        ))
        .execute()
```

It serializes and deserializes fine, however it doesn't write correct JSON to MySQL:

```sql
mysql> select * from JsonPayload;
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| name | rules                                                                                                                                         | defaultValue |
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Test | ["Rule(name=rule1, test=false, rule=RuleTest(name=rule1, test=false))", "Rule(name=rule2, test=true, rule=RuleTest(name=rule1, test=false))"] |            1 |
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

This is the demo project I created to demonstrate this behaviour https://github.com/v1ctor/jooq-json-demo

Can you please help me to understand how to write correct Json to MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an interesting feature idea, which isn't supported yet by the [`DefaultRecordUnmapper`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DefaultRecordUnmapper.html) implementation in jOOQ. I've created  feature requests for this:

- [#13604](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13604) The possibility to make reflective use of Jackson from the `DefaultRecordUnmapper`
- [#13605](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13605) The possibility to use out of the box Jackson converters in the code generator

Currently, Jackson can only be used for mapping `JSON` and `JSONB` to your own data structures when *reading from* the database. Not when *writing to* the database. But there isn't any reason why the inverse logic shouldn't be available as well.

In the meantime, you have to implement a data type `Converter<JSON, List<Rule>>` (or a `Binding`, if you need more power) and attach that to your generated code, see:

- https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/

The benefit of using a `Converter` is that you now get type safety whenever you read/write to this column.